# About Google Plus API and Zend GData

Tags: zend-framework, google-plus, gdata

Well, recently I am writing something as facebook activity. I want to support the google plus platform, so I search about the google plus API library in PHP, and find that there is two source I can choose: Google Plus API and Zend GData.

Then, there is a funny situation. Google Plus API in PHP library and Zend GData are two different library. Google Plus API can allow me post comment as activity, and Zend GData can allow me to post image. The facebook activity things can allow the user post comment only, or the user can post both comment and image.

I am thinking if the user post comment, I call Google Plus API. If the user post comment and image, I call Zend GData? This will make the code very confuse. Can I post the image and comment as activity in google plus API? Or can I post the comment only by using Zend GData?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken the [Google+ api](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) really doesn't exist yet (currently only supports limited GET activity in Developer Preview) and the Zend Gdata component predates Google+ by many years.

I'm sure you can POST images to Picasa and comments to other google services that maybe are reflected on Google+, but any library that is actually POSTing to Google+ is likely a hack.

So to answer the question:

> Can I post the image and comment as activity in google plus API?

The answer would be, NO.